# Download ics file using fullcalendar

Tags: download, fullcalendar, icalendar

Is there any property or event to allow users to download ics file (calendar) using `FullCalendar.min.js`?

I see lots of excellend properties (https://fullcalendar.io/download )but not able to find out download property which can give .ics file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show your code trials please. Also explain what are excellend properties?

Comment: No there isn't. fullCalendar is a GUI application, it's not part of its purpose to allow users to download their data in some other format. fullCalendar reads event data in JSON format. If you want to supply data in another format  you can implement that on your server side.